# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of null (reading 'detail')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

useEffect(() => {
document.title = `View Orders | Bothub`;

```
fetch(`${backendAppUrl}/orders/all`, {
  ...getRequestParams("POST", {
    uid: localStorage.uid,
    idToken: localStorage.idToken,
    user: 0,
    pagination: 1,
  }),
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then(
    (res) => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res.detail === "db-error" || res.detail === "forbidden") {
        setError(true);
        setLoading(false);
      } else {
        const val = res.data;
        setOrders(val);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      setError(true);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  );
// eslint-disable-next-line
```

}, []);

Why does it show like this and throw an error?
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of null (reading 'detail')

Comment: The only code shown which reads a property called `detail` is: `if (res.detail === "db-error" || res.detail === "forbidden")`  If that's the case then `res` is `null`.  Does your `console.log` confirm this?  In your browser's debugging tools, what is the response from the server for this AJAX request?

Comment: Yes, it shows null in the console

Answer (score 0):

If this is showing `null` in the console:

```
console.log(res);
```

Then the JSON response was empty (though somehow still valid I guess) and there's no object to use.  So the code needs to be able to handle a `null` value in `res`.  For example:

```
if (res?.detail === "db-error" || res?.detail === "forbidden") {
  setError(true);
  setLoading(false);
} else {
  const val = res?.data;
  setOrders(val);
  setLoading(false);
}
```

This uses [nullish-safe optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to examine the properties of `res` or just return `null`.  So when `res` is `null` then the `if` condition will be `false` and the `else` block will execute.

Alternatively, if you want the system to handle `null` differently, you'd perform that check in your logic.  For example:

```
if (!res) {
  // respond to null in some way here
} else if (res.detail === "db-error" || res.detail === "forbidden") {
  setError(true);
  setLoading(false);
} else {
  const val = res.data;
  setOrders(val);
  setLoading(false);
}
```

Any way you structure it, the point is that `res` is `null` and your code assumes that it isn't, which produces the error.